# merge array of object based on same key and value

Tags: arrays, typescript, performance

### The Problem

given input:

```
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, a: '1a', b: '1b' },
  { id: 2, a: '2a', b: '2b' }
  ...
]

const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, c: '1c', d: '1d' },
  { id: 2, c: '2c', d: '2d' }
  ...
]
```

disired output:

```
[
  { id: 1, a: '1a', b: '1b', c: '1c', d: '1d' },
  { id: 2, a: '2a', b: '2b', c: '2c', d: '2d' }
  ...
]
```

### Solution 1

```
arr1.map(item => ({ ...item, ...arr2.find(i => i.id === item.id) }))
```

### Soution 2

assume we already have a util function `arrayToMapById` which convert `arr2` to the following:

```
{
  1: { c: '1c', d: '1d' },
  2: { c: '2c', d: '2d' }
  ...
}
```

and the implementation is as following:

```
const arrayToMapById = (arr) => arr.reduce((prev, {id, ...rest}) => ({
  ...prev
  [id]: rest
}), {})
```

then we can get the output by

```
const arr2IdMap = arrayToMapById(arr2)
arr1.map(item => ({ ...item, ...arr2IdMap[item.id] }))
```

### Discussion

solution 1 is conducted naturally and widely accepted/used, however my worry is the performance since `array.find` is used inside each `array.map` iteration, hence we have solution 2; but I also see people saying prototype methods are already optimized, it is faster that you expected and the difference between these 2 solutions is very small.

I am curious is solution 2 a better solution in terms of performace( and by how), and is there a better operation to solve the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't know how this question can be answered objectively. The code isn't a [mre] because we don't have an implementation of `arrayToMapById`, and even with one it's not clear by what measures we should compare performance. Yes, object indexes tend to scale better than array traversals, but… how big are the arrays? How often are you performing these operations? On which runtime engines and hardware? Do we care about time? Memory? Etc... Generally I'd only start caring about performance if I saw a performance *problem*, and then I'd want to see some profiling.

Comment: thanks for the comment, the implementation of `arrayToMapById` is added on the description, let me make some clarifications:

1. I am currently writing React applications, so I am always careful when I am writing data computing/transforming logics to avoid slow render
2. Only caring about preformance issue when there is a one, you are correct, and that's also what react suggests.

Comment: 3. currenly array lenghth is under 1000, so it makes no big difference yet whichever solution I choose, but the size may scale(but very slowly)

Comment: 4. since it's react appilcation, it is run on user-end browser(mostly chrome)
5. it's an open discussion, I don't have any performance metrics to provide, like I said, I am just curious, thanks for your reply again

Comment: The only way to make reliable statements on the performance of a certain piece of code (other than a theoretical `O(..)` class) is to do performance measurements

Comment: My thoughts - solution 2 is creating a new large temporary array which is bad because consumes memory and therefore must be slow. But agree, performance measurements is the only objective way.